# how can i split the string by using charAt() function?

Tags: java, charat

I'm trying to split a sentence which is contain 3 different parts, and they are breakup by blank.

I've tried using boolean to count where is need to move to next part, but it still not work and return null...

```
String sentence="name   password   A";
String username;
String password;
char type;

for(int j=0;j<sentence.length();j++){
   SS=sentence.charAt(i)
   String usernamehelper="";
   String passwordhelper="";
   char typehelper=' ';
   boolean usernameend=false;
   boolean passwordend=false;
   boolean typeend=false;

   if(SS!=' ' && usernameend==false){
        usernamehelper += String.valueOf(SS);
   }else if(SS==' ' && usernameend==false){
        usernameend=true;
   }else if(SS!=' ' && usernameend==true && passwordend==false){
        passwordhelper += String.valueOf(SS);
   }else if(SS==' ' && usernameend==true && passwordend==false){
        passwordend=true;
   }else if(SS!=' ' && usernameend==true && passwordend==true){
        typehelper=SS;
        typeend=true;
        username=usernamehelper;
        password=passwordhelper;
        type=typehelper;
        user1=new user(username, password, type);
   }
}
```

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Are you required to use `charAt()` or are you interested in an easier way?

Comment: Use proper indenting when posting code. This will make your code easier to read and will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You not only have formatting problems but significant syntax errors.  Missing semicolons, undeclared types, etc.  Please re-edit this and ensure it at least compiles correctly.

Comment: I do not understand why you are not using `String.split("   ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , there is a lot of problems with your code such as : variables initialized inside the for loop , missing semicolons ...

Also , having multiple spaces separating the text is what causing you problems.

I tried to correct your code using less if branchs . See code below

```
    String sentence="name    password    A";
    String username = "";
    String password ="";
    char SS ;

    //Result : name , password , type
    String[] result = new String[3] ;
    int i= 0 ;

    // To treat multiple spaces 
    boolean previousSpace = false ;

    String textHelper="";

    for(int j=0;j<sentence.length();j++){
        SS=sentence.charAt(j);
        char typehelper=' ';
        boolean typeend=false;

        if(SS!=' '){
            textHelper+=String.valueOf(SS);
            previousSpace = false ;
        }else if(SS==' ' && previousSpace == false ){
            result[i] = textHelper ;    
            textHelper = "" ;
            previousSpace = true ;
            i++ ;
        }

    }

    //Last Text ( type )
    result[i]= textHelper ;

    System.out.println("username " + result[0]);
    System.out.println("password " +result[1]);
    System.out.println("type " + result[2]);
```

However , you can do all of this in just two lines using split("\\s+") method.

**\\s+** : matches sequence of one or more whitespace characters
 See code below

```
    String sentence="name    password    A";
    String[] result =sentence.split("\\s+");

    System.out.println("username " + result[0]);
    System.out.println("password " +result[1]);
    System.out.println("type " + result[2]);
```